# is there any IAM solution which don't use per user pricing schema?

Tags: authentication, price, identity-management

i made a research on IAM tools and its seems that most of them are using per-active user fees for their pricing schema, and I found it so costly for large amount of user numbers
is there any product tool that uses a different pricing schema?

i search Auth0 , Fusion , StrongDM , onelogin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a SaaS product, you could look at an open-source self-hosted IDP such as [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/). With this option you'll need to host and manage this yourself, but you won't be paying based on the number of users or the number of unique authentications per month.

FYI., if you want paid support for Keycloak, then you can look at [Red Hat Single Sign-On](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-single-sign-on) (RH-SSO) which is based on the Keycloak project. Pricing for RH-SSO is also not based on number of users, but rather the number of cores (or vCPUs) you install it on.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for hoop.dev
Per user pricing is the cheapest you'll find for this type of tool. Other options with pricing based on number of assets managed and their sizes will most likely cost you more and make things pretty rigid.

Make an ROI calculation of the solution you pick. If the tool returns at least 10x the value you pay, it is cheap. There is one calculator for this type of product here: https://hoop.dev/roi